# Use the whole screen to display a shader / material

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, unity-editor

I created a hlsl shader which is rendering a sierpinski fractal using Raymarching. Currently I have assigned the shader to a material, this material is assigned to a cube which I placed in the scene. So the sierpinski fractal is displayed / rendered on the cube geometry.

How can I use the whole screen / camera view to display my shader? I don’t want to add my shader to a material which I assign to a geometry.
[image: Here I selected the cube GO where the material is attached to]

Comment: You might be able to do it with this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderReplacement.html, by using an overlay or background/skybox replacement shader.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into this direction! I will try it and report if it’s working for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is coming to this question and have the same problem as I had, you can do the following:

- use a Graphics.Blit to execute a certain shader
- store this information in a RenderTexture
- assign this RenderTexture to e.g. a Canvas RawImage.texture